# Unable to retrive rows when using Where instead of On

Tags: mysql, oracle, oracle11g

Though my question seems simple but I am unable to trace what's worng with the below query.

```
SELECT * FROM A
INNER JOIN B 
Where 
A.Column1= B.Column1
```

Above query is returning exception at where but when I write as below query is working fine.

```
SELECT * FROM A
INNER JOIN B 
ON
A.Column1= B.Column1
```

Please help me to understand why  I am unable to fetch rows when using `where` instead of `On`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query with WHERE should look as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM A, B
Where 
A.Column1 = B.Column1
```

Comment: Thanks @Ushuaia.. that solved how I missed such simple syntax.. will accept answer once waiting time is over

Comment: I need one more help.. this is fine for inner join but how can I achieve `left outer join` in the same way

Comment: @siva: for left and right join you must join tables by on clause even you can do further filteration in where clause. You can say that comma join, join, inner join are works in same way while left join and rights join are different from it.

Comment: @ZafarMalik Thanks for your info will follow as you suggested.

Comment: It is not good way, but something like this can be used: `select * from A, B
where A.Column1 = b.Column1
union all
select *, null, null, null from a where A.Column1 not in (select Column1 from B)`... the number of null-values should correspond to the number of fields in second table

Comment: @ushuaia Thanks for your response will give it a try